# Parameterized macros involving the ## operator in the replacement-list

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In the book that I am reading "*C Programming A Modern Approach*", there is a section on Page 343 that discusses some tricks you can use to get around certain deficits in macros.

The example problem is depicted as follows:

`#define CONCAT(x,y) x##y` (**Directive 1**)

The author then explains that the following line of code will fail to function as intended if using the aforementioned directive:

`CONCAT(a, CONCAT(b,c))`
This line of code will result in `aCONCAT(b,c)` as opposed to the desired `abc`.

In order to address this shortcoming, the author proposes the following work-around:

`#define CONCAT2(x,y) CONCAT(x,y)`  (**Directive 2**)

The author explains that the presence of **Directive 1** and **Directive 2** will ensure that the *slightly different* line of code `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT2(b,c))` is correctly replaced with `abc`.

(notice that this line of code is different than the original line of code...`CONCAT2` is used instead of `CONCAT`.)

Could someone please walk me through why this will successfully carry out the desired objective? From what I understand, the preprocesser will keep scanning the precompiled code until all defined terms have been dealt with. For a given scan, how many defined words are updated per line?

I would think that the following flow of preprocessing replacements take place:

Given `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT2(b,c))`...

First pass over: `CONCAT(a, CONCAT2(b,c))`

However, for the second pass over, does `CONCAT` get expanded to its replacement list expression? Or does `CONCAT2` get expanded to its replacement list expression? In either case, it seems like we once again arrive at a failed expression of either `aCONCAT2(b,c)` or `CONCAT(a, CONCAT(b,c))`, which would therefore still fail just like the very original case we presented.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the preprocessor detects a function-like macro invocation while scanning a source line, it completely expands the macro's arguments before substituting them into the macro's replacement text, ***except*** that where an argument appears as an operand of the stringification (`#`) or token-pasting (`##`) operator, its literal value is used for the operation.  The resulting replacement text, with expanded arguments and the results of any `#` and `##` operations substituted, is then rescanned for additional macros to expand.

Thus, with ...

```
CONCAT(a, CONCAT(b,c))
```

... the literal values of both arguments are used as operands for the token-pasting operation.  The result is ...

```
aCONCAT(b,c)
```

.  That is rescanned for further macros to expand, but `aCONCAT` is not defined as a macro name, so no further macro expansion occurs.

Now consider ...

```
CONCAT2(a, CONCAT2(b,c))
```

.  *In `CONCAT2`*, neither argument is an operand of `#` or `##`, so both are fully macro-expanded before being substituted.  Of course `a` is unchanged, but `CONCAT2(b,c)` expands to `CONCAT(b,c)`, which upon rescan is expanded to `bc`.  By substitution of the expanded argument values into its replacement text, the outer `CONCAT2` invocation expands to ...

```
CONCAT(a, bc)
```

. That expansion is then rescanned, in the context of the surrounding source text, for further macro expansion, yielding ...

```
abc
```

.  That is again rescanned, but there are no further macro expansions to perform, so that's the final result.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Perhaps I misunderstood, but after the first conversion of `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT2(b,c))` to `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT(b,c))`, why does the `CONCAT(b,c)` expansion take place first before the `CONCAT2(a, ...)` expansion? It seems like there is some order of precedence that takes place here?

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding the difference between the terms "substitute" and "expand"

Comment: Is this the correct sequence of changes? `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT2(b, c))` --> `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT(b, c))` --> `CONCAT2(a, bc)` --> `CONCAT(a, bc)` --> `abc`

Comment: @S.Cramer, If you want to construe the steps of the expansion as going through `CONCAT2(a, CONCAT(b,c))` (I would not and did not describe it that way, but I can work with it), then the `CONCAT(b, c)` expansion takes place first because `CONCAT(b, c)` is an argument to the (outer) `CONCAT2()` invocation, and in that macro's replacement text, the corresponding parameter is not used as an operand of a `#` or `##` operator.  You would achieve the same result by starting from that in the first place.